# How to $unset the whole object instead of leaving it empty or null in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following `update query`, which takes away the content of the `object`,  however it leaves `empty`. I want to get rid of the whole object `{}`.

How can I do that? I have also tried, specifying the `value` for the `properties` instead of the `booleans`, which gives me the same `result`.

If I do this `{ $unset: { "courses.1.teachers.1": 1 }`, that gives me `null` instead of `{}`. So none of them is optimal.

```
student.updateStudent = (fcallback) => {
    var studentObjectId = global.mongoId("5a019896f89c24926108e2bf")
    global.db.collection('students').updateOne({ "_id": studentObjectId }, { $unset: { "courses.1.teachers.1.firstName": 1, "courses.1.teachers.1.lastName": 1 } }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            var jError = { "status": "error", "message": "ERROR -> user.js -> 001" }
            console.log(jError)
            return fcallback(true, jError)
        }
        var jOk = { "status": "ok", "message": "user.js -> deleted -> 000" }
        console.log(jOk)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
        return fcallback(false, jOk)
    })
}
```

This is the result which leaves an empty object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a019896f89c24926108e2bf"),
    "firstName" : "Sarah",
    "lastName" : "Jepsen",
    "age" : 27,
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "courseName" : "Web-development",
            "teachers" : [ 
                {
                    "firstName" : "Santiago",
                    "lastName" : "Donoso"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "courseName" : "Databases",
            "teachers" : [ 
                {
                    "firstName" : "Dany",
                    "lastName" : "Kallas"
                }, 
                {} //see here
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "teachers" : [ 
                {
                    "firstName" : "Roxana",
                    "lastName" : "Stolniceanu"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want is this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a019896f89c24926108e2bf"),
    "firstName" : "Sarah",
    "lastName" : "Jepsen",
    "age" : 27,
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "courseName" : "Web-development",
            "teachers" : [ 
                {
                    "firstName" : "Santiago",
                    "lastName" : "Donoso"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "courseName" : "Databases",
            "teachers" : [ 
                {
                    "firstName" : "Dany",
                    "lastName" : "Kallas"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "teachers" : [ 
                {
                    "firstName" : "Roxana",
                    "lastName" : "Stolniceanu"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`$unset` docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset#behavior), this is the desired behaviour:

> When used with $ to match an array element, $unset replaces the matching element with null rather than removing the matching element from the array. This behavior keeps consistent the array size and element positions.

So you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Right tools:

1. [`$pop`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/) operator: removes first or last array element
2. [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator: removes item based on condition

document for examples:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a019896f89c24926108e2bf"),
    "firstName" : "Sarah",
    "lastName" : "Jepsen",
    "age" : 27,
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "courseName" : "Web-development",
            "teachers" : [ 
                {
                    "firstName" : "Santiago",
                    "lastName" : "Donoso"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "courseName" : "Databases",
            "teachers" : [ 
                {
                    "firstName" : "Dany",
                    "lastName" : "Kallas"
                }, 
                {
                    "firstName": "Code",
                    "lastName": "Dragon"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "teachers" : [ 
                {
                    "firstName" : "Roxana",
                    "lastName" : "Stolniceanu"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

example 1: `$pop`:

```
global.db
    .collection('students')
    .updateOne(
        { _id : studentObjectId },
        { $pop: { "courses.1.teachers": 1 } } // 1 for last item, -1 for the first
    )
```

example 2: `$pull`:

```
global.db
    .collection('students')
    .updateOne(
        { _id  : studentObjectId },
        { $pull: { "courses.1.teachers": { firstName: 'Code' } } }
    )
```